# Jquery -assign linenumbers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

how to assign line numbers for a textarea using jquery.the line numbers are suppose to appear on the lefyside of the textarea

```
    <textarea name='comments' id='comments' cols=10 rows=10></textarea>
```

And the linenumbers and text should be inline with eachother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this previous answer

[Html adding line numbers to textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995370/html-adding-line-numbers-to-textarea)

the best result being:

http://files.aw20.net/jquery-linedtextarea/jquery-linedtextarea.html