# line numbers using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

```
  <div id="line_numbers"></div>
  <textarea cols="65" rows="15" name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
  <textarea cols="65" rows="15" name="matches" id ="matches"></textarea>
```

there are many examples out there(
[Html adding line numbers to textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995370/html-adding-line-numbers-to-textarea)
) but i just want to implement  line numbers for a text area using jquery.Please let me know how to go about it.Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked into any plugins. However, here's a simple way for you to get started.

**CSS:**

```
#line_numbers {clear:both; float: left; text-align: right}
```

**jQuery:**

```
   $("#comments").change(function() {
     var comment_lines = $("#comments").val().split('\n');      
     $("#line_numbers").html('');
     for(i = 0; i < comment_lines.length; i++) {
        $("#line_numbers").html($("#line_numbers").html() + (i+1) + "<br/>");
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but there's also the [JQuery Lined TextArea plugin](http://alan.blog-city.com/jquerylinedtextarea.htm).