# How to have a html textarea for a program/code that prints evrey line

Tags: html, css, textarea

Does anybody know how to create a html textarea with css or java that displays a textarea that's for code. For example,  the textarea in, skulpt.org .How do you print the line numbers?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: http://www.skulpt.org

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995370/html-adding-line-numbers-to-textarea