# Angular - Add line number to teaxtarea without jQuery

Tags: angularjs, textarea

I am trying to add line number to a `textarea` and the only options that I found are based on jQuery, for [exapmle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995370/html-adding-line-numbers-to-textarea).
Is there a way to do it using `angular` only ot pure CSS/JS?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want jQuery answers (which is absolutely fine), don't tag your question with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this shouldn't be a problem. One solution might be to use ng-repeat to create small line number divs next to the textarea. Something like this:

```
  <div class="line-numbers">
      <div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number)">{{$index+1}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-area">
    <textarea rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
  </div>
```

And this in your controller:

```
  $scope.number = 5;
  $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);
  }
```

With some CSS to help them sit next to each other:

```
.line-numbers {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: fixed-width;
  margin: 0px;
}

.text-area {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Good luck!