# Display Line number in textarea without jquery

Tags: html, css

I am having some issue regarding displaying line number in textarea and i don't want to use jQuery for displaying the line number. i tried a simple CSS trick to display the line number that is:

```
.linenumber{
    background-attachment: local;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-color:#ccc;
}
```

but that not worked for my [page](http://www.mycodemyway.com/beautifiers/json-parser). I believe that bootstrap is causing issue because when i tried with different file it work can anyone please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995370/html-adding-line-numbers-to-textarea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
textarea
{
 background: url(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png);
 background-attachment: local;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 padding-left: 35px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 border-color:#ccc;
 line-height:16px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it work for me i missed the background.

Comment: Oooo...Perfect solution.... You Saved My Life..!!!!!!  Big Thank you...@Riddhi rathod

Comment: Hi @Riddhi Rathod do you know why its scroll down is not working in Mozilla and how can I change the line number?