# Textarea with alternate rows and line numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I'm trying to draw a `textarea` with alternate rows and line numbers.
A very simple solution to have line numbers is the following - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995370/html-adding-line-numbers-to-textarea) for more details.

```css
textarea {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png);
  background-attachment: local;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
```

While to have a `textarea` with alternate rows is just a simple as

```css
textarea {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#F1F1F1 50%, #F9F9F9 50%);
  background-size: 100% 4rem;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Both solutions works ok, but combining them it's tricky since both makes use of the `background` to hack the line numbers and the alternate rows background.

Comment: Can you put two textareas next to each other with the scrollbar on an outer, containing div?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could combine them by wrapping your `textarea` in a `div` then assign the stripped background styles to that wrapping div, so the 2 backgrounds are like layered.

```css
textarea {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png);
  background-attachment: local;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-color: #ccc;

  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.textarea-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#F1F1F1 50%, #F9F9F9 50%);
  background-size: 100% 32px;
  background-position: left 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-wrapper">
  <textarea rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
</div>
```

The wrapping div I set to `display: inline-block` so it wraps the `textarea` like an inline element and I positioned the background gradient 10px from the top to account for you padding-top.

You may have to play with the background size of the gradient to get it to properly match the line-height of the `textarea`.

**UPDATE**
To @DavidThomas's point, to help line up your text with the alternating gradient the background-size height value should be 2 times the line-height of the textarea (see updated snippet). But the harder thing is to make it line up with the image numbers.

Comment: If you enter characters, and hit return for a new line, you'll see that the numbers don't line up with the line-height. You'll need to account for the the `<div>` and `<textarea>` having different `font`, `font-size` and `line-height`.

Comment: @DavidThomas See the update. The main issue is lining up everything with the image that has the numbers. But his question is regarding merging the image backgrounds... not lining up things exactly.

Comment: Any way to keep the lines lined up with the alternating background lines when scrolling vertically?

Answer (score 2):

You could use multiple backgrounds for the same element.

> CSS allows you to add multiple background images for an element, through the `background-image` property.

**In you case:**

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/2cOaJ.png) top -12px left / auto no-repeat, 
              linear-gradient(#F1F1F1 50%, #F9F9F9 50%) top left / 100% 32px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  resize: vertical;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that after typing characters, hitting return for a new-line, and then continuing to type the user can only enter text on alternate line-numbers, which is a slightly odd user experience (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeFYQ.png); also: the padding. :)

Comment: You're right. I was only providing here a solution for merging both images.