# How do I make local attached repeating linear gradients

Tags: html, css, background-attachment, repeating-linear-gradient

I've recently been trying to make a text area that uses a repeating linear gradient to separate lines, however, the gradient does not attach to the textbox when I'm scrolling.
Am I doing something wrong?

By the way, here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="TextareaWrapper"><textarea id="Text" cols="1500"></textarea></div>
  </body>
</html>
<style>
  #Text
  {
    background: url("https://www.linkpicture.com/q/2cOaJ-2.png");
    background-size: 30px 33325px;
    background-position: 0px 11px;
    background-attachment: local;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-color:#ccc;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 400px;
    height: 225px
  }
  .TextareaWrapper
  {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f0f0f0 50%);
    background-attachment: local;
    background-size: 100% 45px;
    background-position: left 10px;
  }
</style>
<script>

</script>
```

Also, here are some URLs that I used:

[Numbered and separated rows in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369434/textarea-with-alternate-rows-and-line-numbers/52369720)

[Repeating Linear Gradient Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the element you are scrolling is `textarea`, not `.TextareaWrapper`, so the `background-attachment: local` can not apply the scrolling for its children.

You may combine these two background images into one `background` property with comma separated shorthands, and you don't even need the `TextareaWrapper` anymore.

```css
background: url("https://www.linkpicture.com/q/2cOaJ-2.png") 0px 11px/30px 33325px local no-repeat, repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f0f0f0 50%) left 10px/100% 45px local;
```

Those two backgrounds will be merged into one image to share the same scrolling position:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="TextareaWrapper"><textarea id="Text" cols="1500"></textarea></div>
  </body>
</html>
<style>
  #Text
  {
    background: url("https://www.linkpicture.com/q/2cOaJ-2.png") 0px 11px/30px 33325px local no-repeat, repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f0f0f0 50%) left 10px/100% 45px local;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-color:#ccc;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 400px;
    height: 225px
  }
</style>
<script>

</script>
```