# TEXTAREA Wrap Attribute Soft Or Hard

Tags: html, textarea, word-wrap

I read [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_wrap.asp) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#attr-wrap) to learn how the `wrap` attribute of `<textarea>` works. I saw a question here that explains the difference between soft and hard wrap but I can't understand it. Can anyone explain this to me in a more simplified way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wrap: hard` breaks long words into smaller (in case `cols` attribute is set - this will be length of smaller words)

**Wrap: hard**

For example this form will have output `WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWW W` :

```
<form>
  <textarea cols="10" wrap="hard">
  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
  </textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Wrap: soft**

With `wrap: soft` it will have this output (same as value): `WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW`

**Wrap: off**

Also there is option `wrap: off`, which means, that nothing will be split to more lines. A scrollbar will be added instead. It has no change to output, which will be like with `wrap: soft`: `WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW`

```html
<textarea wrap="off">
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with graphical  input. You should notice the difference when the input field size exeeded. For example:

```
<textarea wrap="hard" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Will begin new line each 80 chars. Note it's not supported everywhere/

```
<textarea wrap="soft" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Will begin new line once displayed width exeeded. 
You can also disable line wrap by `wrap="off"`

Code spinnet to play with (have a look at @Arnav Katyal's answer):
[Adding Line Numbers To HTML Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995370/adding-line-numbers-to-html-textarea)

Comment: Consider, line wraps are actually not newlines,  because not contain \n escape char